# Two interfering cakePHP-Installations on nginx/php-fpm server

Tags: cakephp, nginx, open-basedir

I needed to setup two completely separated cakePHP-Environments on my nginx-server (nginx 1.0.5, php5-fpm via fastcgi).

I created the following folder-structure:

```
/var/www
  /**virtual1**/
    /app
    /lib/Cake/..
  /**virtual2**/
    /app
    /lib/Cake/..
```

Now, when I call virtual1.mydomain.com I see my front-end-app and can use it.
But, when I call virtual2.mydoamin.com I get strange errors (like when virtual2 includes some of the files of virtual1..) Virtual1 is working anyway.

Now I clear my browser cache & my cookies and reload `virtual2.mydomain.com`. Now I can use this app without any problems BUT `virtual1.mydomain.com` show strange errors.

Okay - Now I limited each host to his own directory using open_basedir. Result:

```
Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/virtual1/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/taskees:/usr/share/php5:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in /var/www/virtual2/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505

Warning: include(/var/www/virtual1/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/virtual2/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/virtual1/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/virtual2/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/virtual2/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505

Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/virtual1/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/taskees:/usr/share/php5:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in /var/www/virtual2/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505

Warning: include(/var/www/virtual1/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/virtual2/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/virtual1/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/virtual2/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/virtual2/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505 Fatal error: Class 'CakePlugin' not found in /var/www/virtual2/app/Config/bootstrap.php on line 67
```

**Edit:** I get the same errors when I call these pages from a different computer operating on a different internet-connection :(

okay - Why the hell do these cakePHP-Installations try to get files from the each time other installation

AND WHY DOES THIS CHANGE EVERYTIME AFTER CLEARING CACHE AND COOKIES?

Comment: this is definitly a cakephp-cache issue. When I set duration of file-caching in core.php to 1second I do not need to clear my cache. I just need to wait 1 second.

So how to solve this issue without disabling cache completely?

const CACHE refers to the each time correct path in each app. So why the hell do the both caches interfere?

Comment: This seems to be an APC-Caching-Engine issue. When I switch caching-engine to "file" everything works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooh, I have an idea.  How is the cacheing being stored?  Is it using a database, or is it storing to file.  If you have multiple installs, but only one db, make sure the caches are storing to file.

As a debug measure, make two databases using mysqldump.  Separate them in the config/database.php files for each install, then check the problem again.  If it goes away, then something in the cacheing is being written to db (which you don't want).

Comment: Thank u for this idea :) I just checked on that and sadly there is no such cache-table in my database.. So it must be stored at file-level.

When I debug the CACHE-constants in both installation, I get the each time correct location in their repectively app-folder.. strange!